# Prove properties of inner product norm

Tags: linear-algebra

```
I need to prove these for the general inner product not euclidean inner product.
```

1) $||u|| \ge 0$
2)$||u|| = 0$ iff $u=0$
3)$||ku|| = |k| ||u||$

for the euclidean inner product its pretty straight forward but more generally I'm not sure how to proceed

1) $||u||= \sqrt{<u,u>}$

I'm not sure what to do from here because it needs to be generalized

Comment: These properties are normally taken as the *definition* of the inner product.  If your book uses a different definition, you will need to provide that so we can prove these properties.

Comment: It gives them as the definition then in the exercises says to prove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) follows directly from the properties of an inner product. Look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html. For (2), we have, if $u=0$, then
$$||u|| = \sqrt{\langle 0, 0 \rangle} = \sqrt{0} = 0,$$
and if $||u|| = 0$, then
$$||u|| = \sqrt{\langle u, u \rangle} = 0 \iff \langle u, u \rangle = 0^2 = 0 \iff u = 0,$$
where the last "if and only if" follows from (4) on the page I linked you to. As for 3), we have
$$||ku|| = \sqrt{\langle ku, ku \rangle} = \sqrt{k^2 \langle u, u \rangle} = |k| \sqrt{\langle u, u\rangle} = |k| * ||u||.$$

Comment: okay yeah that looks good for (3), the other ones I can see how to prove them using a given type of inner product but in general. all I can show is $||u||=\sqrt{<u,u>} \ge 0$ and if $u=0$ then $||u||=||0||=\sqrt{<0,0>}=0$

Comment: I edited my answer to address your question.